# How to filter a dataset by the time stamp

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I'm working with some bird GPS tracking data, and I would like to exclude points based on the time stamp.

Some background information- the GPS loggers track each bird for just over 24 hours, starting in the evening, and continuing through the night and the following day. What I would like to do is exclude points taken after 9:30pm on the day AFTER deployment (so removing points from the very end of the track). 
As an R novice, I'm struggling because the deployment dates differ for each bird, so I can't simply use `subset()` for a specific date and time.

An example of my dataframe (df):

```
BirdID    x             y           Datetime
15K12     492719.9      5634805     2015-06-23 18:25:00
15K12     492491.5      5635018     2015-06-23 18:27:00
15K70     455979.1      5653581     2015-06-24 19:54:00  
15K70     456040.9      5653668     2015-06-24 19:59:00
```

So, pretending these points represent the start of the GPS track for each animal, I would like to remove points after 9:30 pm on June 24 for bird 15K12, and after 9:30 on June 25 for bird 15K70.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe overly pipetastic, but `df %>% group_by(BirdID) %>% filter(Datetime < (Datetime %>% min() %>% as.Date() %>% \`+\`(1) %>% paste('21:30:00') %>% as.POSIXct()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if df$Datetime is a date variable:

```
class(df$Datetime)
```

If it's not, you can convert it with this:

```
df$Datetime <- ymd_hms(df&Datetime)
```

You use mutate to create a new variable called newdate that takes the earliest date of the bird's data and sets the date for cutoff which is the next day at 21:30:00 of the earliest date of a bird's observations.

Then you filter the Datetime column by the newdate column and you get the observations that are found earlier that the specified date.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  group_by(BirdID) %>%
  mutate(newdate = as.POSIXct(date(min(Datetime)) + days(1) + hours(21) + minutes(30))) %>% 
  filter(Datetime < newdate)
```

Did a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)

# Create a data frame (1000 observations)
BirdID <- paste(rep(floor(runif(250, 1, 20)),4),
  rep("k", 1000), rep(floor(runif(250, 1, 40)),4), sep = "")
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 47000, sd = 2000)
y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 5650000, sd = 300000)
Datetime <- as.POSIXct(rnorm(1000, mean = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-06-23 18:25:00")), sd = 99999), tz = "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01")
df <- data.frame(BirdID, x, y, Datetime, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Filter the data frame by the specified date
df_filtered <- df %>% 
  group_by(BirdID) %>%
  mutate(newdate = as.POSIXct(date(min(Datetime)) + days(1) + hours(21) + minutes(30))) %>% 
  filter(Datetime < newdate)
```

This should fix any problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem because I want to retain points taken between 21:30 and 23:59 on the day tracking starts. For example, if tracking starts at 18:00 on June 23, I want to remove points after 21:30 on June 24.

Comment: @Splash1199 I fixed the solution for your specific request :)

Comment: thanks @toku_mo 
The first step worked beautifully. However, when I try to filter Datetime<newdate, nothing happens. Is there something I need to know to be able to do arithmetic with dates?

Comment: @Splash1199 is you df$Datetime column of class Date (POSIXct)? If it's character it won't work. You can convert the column if it's character. Will edit the answer now.

Comment: yes, they are POSIXct. However, I've noticed the time zone for df$newdate is UTC instead of PDT. I've tried to assign the time zone like this: 
`df$newdate <- ymd_hms(date(Datetime) + days(1) + hours(21) + minutes(30), tz="PDT")`

but that didn't work

Comment: @Splash1199 found the error, there's nothing to do about the timezone. The error was that I forgot to pick the earliest observation date and add one day (you said observations were taken in a day's period). The error has been fixed in the answer above.

Comment: I have no idea why I can't get it to work. Datetime is an object of the class POSIXct. I even tried
    `df %>%
    group_by(BirdID) %>%
    mutate(newdate = as.POSIXct(date(min(Datetime)) + days(1) +     hours(21) + minutes(30)))`
But I don't get a new column called newdate. Any idea why?
this is the error I get Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Ok, you need to install the maggritr package that comes with the dplyr package

Comment: @Splash1199 great, pls don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Thank you

Comment: How could I make "newdate" equal to sunset time at the coordinates (50.861675, -129.08731), instead of "21:30:00" (which was a rough approximation of sunset)?

Comment: @Splash1199 this could help http://rud.is/b/2014/09/23/seeing-the-daylight-with-r/